# NiceEdit click issue

Tags: javascript, html, nicedit

I have used nicEditor in my winforms by loading a web browser and loading the nicEditor inside it. By default when the editor loaded and after that I click in the middle of the editor the focus doe not go to nicEditor. But if I click right at the start of the editor, focus is set to the editor. Following is my HTML file code.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var myInstance = "";
        function GetContent() {
            //window.alert(""+myInstance);
            //var content = tinyMCE.get('tinyMceEditor').getContent();
            //content = content.replace("<body>", "<body style=\"font-size:10px;\">");
            //var content = nicEditors.get('area3').getContent();
            var content = myInstance.instanceById('editor').getContent();
            //window.alert(myInstance.instanceById('editor').getContent());
            return content;
        }
        function SetContent(htmlContent) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                //window.alert(htmlContent);
                //nicEditors.get('area3').setContent(htmlContent);
                myInstance.instanceById('editor').setContent(htmlContent);

                if (htmlContent == undefined || htmlContent == '')
                    myInstance.instanceById('editor').setContent('');

                //tinyMCE.get('tinyMceEditor').readOnly = true;
            }, 100);
        }     
    </script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jscripts/nicEdit.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        bkLib.onDomLoaded(function () {
            //myInstance = new nicEditor().panelInstance('editor');
            myInstance = new nicEditor({ maxHeight: 388 }).panelInstance('editor');

            //nicEditors.allTextAreas() 
        });
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px;">
    <div id="sample">
        <textarea id="demo" cols="50" id="editor" name="editor" style="width:295px;" >
        </textarea>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please help.

Comment: can you send your jquery code for nicEdit.js ? or give the online path for the same ?

Comment: http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js" or see the website : 

http://nicedit.com/demos.php?demo=2

Comment: can you tell me why you have used those script code ? and that function ? is it require for you ?

Comment: without your script code i tried and the texteditor is working .

Comment: @PunitGajjar : what you mean by your script.? Can you post your code.?

Comment: talking about your function  "function GetContent() { } "

do you need that all ?

Comment: Yes. As I will have to populate the saved data back when user edits the record.

Answer (score 0):

Its working with this way. 
but i am not getting what you are trying to do using below script .

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        bkLib.onDomLoaded(function () {
            //myInstance = new nicEditor().panelInstance('editor');
            myInstance = new nicEditor({ maxHeight: 388 }).panelInstance('editor');

            //nicEditors.allTextAreas() 
        });
</script>
```

here is my simple HTML .  Now let me know what exactly you want to do .

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body style="margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px;">
        <div id="sample">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                //<![CDATA[
                bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
                //]]>

            </script>
            <textarea id="demo" cols="50" id="editor" name="editor" style="width:295px;" >
            </textarea>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When this will be rendered, the nicEditor will be of height 388. When clicked in the middle of the text area, focus should be on the editor. In my case that doesn't happen. When I click on the extact start of the editor then only it is in focus.

Comment: I tried your solution. The editor is not or height 338

Comment: you want the height 338px for editor or textarea ? and what should be the height of text area when user focus() it.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for something like this,
Just let me know if i am wrong anywhere.

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .heightClass {
            min-height: 338px !important;
        }
        </style>
    <body style="margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 0px;">
        <div id="sample">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://js.nicedit.com/nicEdit-latest.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                //<![CDATA[
                bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { nicEditors.allTextAreas() });
                //]]>
                $(document).on("focus" , ".nicEdit-selected" , function () {
                   var parentTag = $( this ).css("height" , "338px");
                   //$( this ).addClass("heightClass");
                   //alert(parentTag);
                });
            </script>
            <textarea id="demo" cols="50" id="editor" name="editor" style="width:295px;" >
            </textarea>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```